# MySQL filter many elements from many-to-many relationship

Tags: mysql, sql, many-to-many, conditional-statements

I'm currently working on objects that are linked through a many-to-any relationship (it means that many objects can be linked to... not many objects of the same type, but many objects which type can vary).

But, for this question, a many-to-many will be plenty enough.

So, let's say I have a ObjectA table, with the following :

```sql
CREATE TABLE (
    id INT(11) NOT NULL, 
    label VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    -- primary keys and all the stuff
);

CREATE TABLE ObjectB (
    id INT(11) NOT NULL,
    label VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    -- primary keys and all the stuff
);

CREATE TABLE ObjectA_ObjectB (
    objectA_id INT(11) NOT NULL,
    objectA_type VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL, -- for the many to any
    objectB_id INT(11) NOT NULL,
    -- primary keys and all the stuff
);
```

Let's say I want to filter the ObjectA with 2 or three elements from ObjectB. You will think that I should use a `IN` :

```sql
SELECT *
    FROM ObjectA a
        LEFT JOIN ObjectA_ObjectB relation ON a.id = relation.objectA_id AND "ObjectA" = relation.objectA_class
        LEFT JOIN ObjectB b ON relation.objectB_id = b.id
    WHERE b.id IN (1, 2, 3);
```

But, the thing is, with this request, it gets all the objectAs that are linked with at least ONE of the ObjectBs searched (here, 1, 2, and 3). But, what I want, are those that have **all** the ObjectB's 1, 2 and 3.

I already tried some things (like the `ALL` possibility, or pondering to make a first filter outside of SQL), but it didn't give the expected results.

Any ideas ?

---

To sum up, I'd like to be able to do a bit like the issues from GitHub and how they are filtering their label. If you pick up a bunch of labels, only the issues that have *all* the selected labels are returned, rather than all the issues that have *at least **one*** label.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comments it sounds like you don't want `LEFT JOIN` which will return ALL `ObjectA`s which match the `WHERE` clause. As for the relation condition you have to count the matching rows:

```
  SELECT *
    FROM ObjectA a
    JOIN ObjectA_ObjectB relation 
      ON a.id = relation.objectA_id 
     AND "ObjectA" = relation.objectA_class
    JOIN ObjectB b 
      ON relation.objectB_id = b.id
GROUP BY a.id
  HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN b.id IN (1,2,3) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)=3;
```

OR:

```
  SELECT *
    FROM ObjectA a
    JOIN ObjectA_ObjectB relation 
      ON a.id = relation.objectA_id 
     AND "ObjectA" = relation.objectA_class
    JOIN ObjectB b 
      ON relation.objectB_id = b.id
     AND b.id IN (1,2,3)
GROUP BY a.id
  HAVING COUNT(*)=3;
```

If you don't actually need the ObjectB data in this query you can simplify this even further:

```
  SELECT a.*
    FROM ObjectA a
    JOIN ObjectA_ObjectB relation 
      ON a.id = relation.objectA_id 
     AND "ObjectA" = relation.objectA_class
     AND relation.objectB_id IN (1,2,3)
GROUP BY a.id
  HAVING COUNT(*)=3;
```

This assumes that you can only have one of each `ObjectB.id` linked to an `ObjectA` through the pivot table.

Comment: Seems fine, but what if an ObjectA has 3 ObjectB linked ? Wouldn't the `COUNT(*)` filter only the ObjectAs that have 2 ObjectBs ?

Comment: Just saw, seems to be fine. I'll have to try on a real scale, but this seems to be pretty adapter. Thanks !

Comment: @Talus Actually I think I prefer my original answer, it would work with ObjectAs with more than three ObjectBs as the JOIN condition only extracts the three rows. I have included both.

Comment: you mean the one with `COUNT(*)` or the one with the embedded condition ? And as a matter of a fact, I need the ObjectB because I'm using something else to search my objects (they have an `id`, but i'm searching with another field, a `hash` which is a composite key)

Comment: @Talus Both the top two queries return almost the same, the ObjectA with one ObjectB record. The top one can have any ObjectB, the middle any ObjectB with id IN (1,2,3)

Comment: Oh yeah I see, but no worries, I'm not selecting `*` in my query, just a few fields from my ObjectA. But I do need the `JOIN` for my filtering, that was all the rambling was about.

Comment: @Talus Use the second one, it'll give you better performance.

Comment: Yeah, but what if my ObjectA has the following ObjectBs : (1, 2, 3, 4) ? Would it be still validated by this query ?

Comment: @Talus Yep, the JOIN only matches Bs with id IN (1,2,3) so count(*) will still be 3.

Comment: Good to know, so this should do the trick. Thanks a lot then :)

Answer (score 1):

A solution is to count the matching conditions in an having clause.

```
SELECT *
FROM ObjectA a
    JOIN ObjectA_ObjectB relation ON a.id = relation.objectA_id AND "ObjectA" = relation.objectA_class
    JOIN ObjectB b ON relation.objectB_id = b.id
WHERE b.id IN (1, 2, 3) GROUP BY a.id HAVING COUNT(b.id)=3;
```

See [sqlfidle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1daf1d/11).

Comment: yep, that's what @Arth was suggesting just below. :)